# What kind of texture/brush is this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

I really need to know what kind of texture this is can someone please help?

[image: Texture image]

Comment: that image is much too small, and the texture to subtle to really define accurately.

Comment: Do you have a better picture of it perhaps?

Comment: @people that voted down: when you vote down, please explain why you voted down.

Comment: I voted down because there is not good content to the question, i.e the image is too small to help us answer accurately. If @Ben improves the resource i'll upvote again

Comment: I think anyone who says 'image is too small' should just open in in PS or something and zoom in. Also, this is probably a background image, so only logical that it's that small. No intention to scold or anything, but I do think it's a weak argument to vote down for. Or even mention.

Answer (score 1):

Although the image ti far too small to see with any sort of clarity, it looks like it is just some noise applied to a solid color.

Filter > Noise > Add Noise

Answer (score 1):

This texture could be a fabric or some other pattern that has been scaled and possibly colored as well. (The linked screenshot is really small, so it's hard to tell.)

Answer (score 1):

I dont get the question, really think about it. If you already have the texture why not just use it (it's not like font that you need to know its name to use it) and if you are looking to find similar ones then search for subtle fabric patterns/textures.
This is the texture you posted:
[image]

and this is the texture i found on internet, not exactly the same but very similar:
**at website called: http://subtlepatterns.com/tag/dark/ .....its name is Stressed Linen.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sort of looks like one of the default fabric type patterns in photoshop

Comment: Well at least not CS3, CS4 or CS5. PS has only few default patterns (and they're not great either).

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's a fabric-like denim. Though I don't quite understand the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I say its a texture/pattern, maybe its the [Apple iOS Linen texture](http://www.premiumpixels.com/freebies/apple-ios-linen-texture/).
[image]

If not, spend some time [on this site, its a great pattern collection](http://subtlepatterns.com/?s=fabric&submit=Search) and maybe you'll find it, or just google for subtle denim/fabric pattern..